How to Efficiently Update Live Scores in React Native App Without Constant API Calls?
I'm working on a React Native project which is a mobile app for displaying soccer live scores. The data is fetched from the server and displayed in the app. However, I want to ensure that the live scores are updated in the app without requiring the user to refresh the entire page. Constantly calling the API to reload the full page is not efficient.
What is the best approach to update the scores in real-time or at regular intervals without overloading the server with frequent full-page API calls?
Here's a brief overview of what I'm doing:

Fetching data from the server using an API.
Displaying the data in the app.
Wanting to update the scores efficiently as they change.

What I've considered so far:
Polling the server at regular intervals (seems inefficient).
Using WebSockets (not sure how to integrate this with React Native).
Any guidance or examples of how to achieve this in React Native would be greatly appreciated!

you can use Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.
